# Why 500 error return json message value is empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, bean-validation

Spring boot app there is a method like below

```
getBasicInfoList(@RequestParam int pageNum, @RequestParam @Max(20)int pageSize)
```

pageSize cannot be more than 20,  and if more than 20, got below return

```
{
  "timestamp": 1602562522208,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "",
  "path": "/convertibleBond/basicInfos"
}
```

and app throw below exception

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: getBasicInfoList.pageSize: must be less than or equal to 20
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
```

So why `message` value is empty? How to let it is `getBasicInfoList.pageSize: must be less than or equal to 20`?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 500 means *look in the server logs for the error*!

Fortunately, you've done this:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: getBasicInfoList.pageSize: must be less than or equal to 20
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
```

That's the problem.  You need to fix it.

Q: So why (JSON) message value is empty?

A: Because the server-side app crashed before it had the chance to write a Json reply.  It's as simple as that.

Fix the Spring Boot (server-side) constraint error, and you'll get HTTP (Json) message responses again.

PS:

You might also consider adding exception handling in your Spring Boot app.  For example: [REST API Error Handling With Spring Boot](https://dzone.com/articles/rest-api-error-handling-with-spring-boot)